# Required return class of _retrieveCollection() in extending Magento API

Tags: api, rest-api

I am creating my own resources by extending the Magento REST API, and I'm stuck on what object class should be returned on _retrieveCollection() for my API to render properly on both XML and JSON output.

My code is, roughly, as follows:

```
class Company_Module_Model_Api2_Invoice extends Mage_Api2_Model_Resource
{
    protected function _retrieveCollection()
    {
        //just can't get the proper object to return here. :(    

    }

    protected function _retrieve() {
        $invoice_increment_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('invoice_id');
        $invoice = Mage::getModel("sales/order_invoice")->loadByIncrementId($invoice_increment_id);
        return $invoice;

        //Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice is a Mage_Sales_Model_Abstract
        //which in turn is a Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
        //Having a Mage_Core_Model_Abstract as a return renders perfectly
        //as json or xml :)

        //Also works with Mage_Sales_Model_Order which is a  
        //Mage_Sales_Model_Abstract which in turn is a
        //Mage_Core_Model_Abstract 
    }

    protected function _create() {
         ....
         //no matter what you return, this doesn't render any output.
    }

    protected function _delete() {
         ...
         //no matter what you return, this doesn't render any output.   
    }
```

So the question is: What is the return type for **_retrieveCollection()**?

UPDATE:

[@danny-dev-nz](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/9199/danny-dev-nz) is correct with `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Invoice_Collection` (and I guess any **`Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract`**)

I realized my problem is Magento versions. This is straightforward on a Magento 1.9.0.1 installation.

```
protected function _retrieveCollection()
{

     $order_increment_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
     $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->loadByIncrementId($order_increment_id);
     $invoices = $order->getInvoiceCollection();
     return $invoices;       

}
```

Output on Magento "1.9.0.1"
[image]

Output on Magento "1.7.0.2" is quirky:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Invoice_Collection` .

Using factory method `Mage::getResourceModel("sales/order_invoice_collection").`

Comment: Great! Though I discovered that this works on Magento 1.9, but not on 1.7. Updated question for this :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, after experimenting and tweaking, I discovered the following data types to be a valid return for _retrieveCollection():

- Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
- String
- Non-nested array of strings, (member nested array would come out as empty array). `array("a","b","c")` is fine while `array("a",array("b","c"))` is not.
- associative array with string as key, and string as value (objects on key nor value will NOT work)

Answer (score 1):

you simply create a Varien_data_collection, fill it up with varien objects and return the collection:

```
    $collection = new Varien_Data_Collection(); 

    foreach ($products_collection as $product) {

        $prod = $product_model->load( $product->getProductId() );

        $v_product = array(
                    'id' => $prod->getId(), 
                    'name' => $prod->getName(),
                    'price' => $prod->getPrice(),
                );

        $varienObject = new Varien_Object();
        $varienObject->setData($v_product);
        $collection->addItem($varienObject);
    }

    return $collection;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
retrieveCollection function give return null value.
```

and function _retrieve()  did  not `give any result as it return as an obeject`. you need  convert obeject to `to  array format`