# _retrieveCollection Return Formatting

Tags: api

I'm trying to return a collection of the products that meets an input criteria using Magento api2. Everything is working as expected other than how Magento formats the final JSON.

What i basically want to do is to return a json with two keys, one is the *totalRecords* specifying the number of items without the sorting (so I can handle the paging on the client side), and the *items* as the actual products. So I made the below tries:

**1. First Try**

The problem I faced here is that i found Magento for some reason always return the first item in the Items key, so I get the right *totalRecords* and the right first item, but i'm not sure what kind of post processing Magento does on the output to stripe the other elements of the array.

```
protected function _retrieveCollection()
{

      $store_id =  $this->getRequest()->getParam('store_id');
      $page_size = $this->getRequest()->getParam('page_size');
      $page = $this->getRequest()->getParam('page');

      /** @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */
      $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
      $collection->setStoreId($store_id);
      $collection->addAttributeToSelect(array_keys(
        $this->getAvailableAttributes($this->getUserType(), Mage_Api2_Model_Resource::OPERATION_ATTRIBUTE_READ)
      ));
      $collection->addFinalPrice();

      if ($page_size) $collection->setPageSize($page_size);
      if ($page) $collection->setCurPage($page);

      $this->_applyCategoryFilter($collection);
      $this->_applyCollectionModifiers($collection);
      $products = $collection->load()->toArray();

      return array(
          'items' => array_values($products),
          'totalRecords' => $collection->getSize()
        );
}
```

**2. Second Try**

The second try was simply using the Varien_Data_Collection. It returns all the items, however the *totalRecords* will be incorrect, since im just copying the results from the products collection to this new collection, which is obviously not the right approach.

```
protected function _retrieveCollection()
{

      $store_id =  $this->getRequest()->getParam('store_id');
      $page_size = $this->getRequest()->getParam('page_size');
      $page = $this->getRequest()->getParam('page');

      /** @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */
      $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
      $collection->setStoreId($store_id);
      $collection->addAttributeToSelect(array_keys(
        $this->getAvailableAttributes($this->getUserType(), Mage_Api2_Model_Resource::OPERATION_ATTRIBUTE_READ)
      ));
      $collection->addFinalPrice();

      if ($page_size) $collection->setPageSize($page_size);
      if ($page) $collection->setCurPage($page);

      $this->_applyCategoryFilter($collection);
      $this->_applyCollectionModifiers($collection);
      $products = $collection->load()->toArray();

      $varien_collection = new Varien_Data_Collection();
      foreach ($products as $key => $value) {
          $varien_object = new Varien_Object();
          $varien_object->setData($value);
          $varien_collection->addItem($varien_object);
      }

      return $varien_collection;
}
```

I think my first try was using the right approach, however i have no clue on why Magento is stripping the other items in the *Items* array.

---

### **Update #1**

After a small discussion with @DigitalPianism, I was thinking there is a problem with the JSON breaking the Magento formatting, however when i try returning something as simple as this:

```
      return array(
          'items' => array(array('r' => 'q'), array('b' => 'f')),
          'totalRecords' => $collection->getSize()
        );
```

only the first item is returned as well, and with the lack of documentation i have no idea why the first array is only returned.

## **Update #2**

Problem is in nested array, outlined here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/33012/13103, not sure how i should return it now :(

## **Update #3**

So digging in how Magento formats the output, i opened `/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Resource.php` as suggested by @DigtialPianisim, to line 243 (Magento 1.9), specifically this block:

```
        case self::ACTION_TYPE_COLLECTION . self::OPERATION_RETRIEVE:
            $this->_errorIfMethodNotExist('_retrieveCollection');
            $retrievedData = $this->_retrieveCollection();
            $filteredData  = $this->getFilter()->collectionOut($retrievedData);
            $this->_render($filteredData);
            break;
```

The problem is what this line does to the output `$this->getFilter()->collectionOut($retrievedData);`, if i just replace the $filteredData with the $retrievedData everything would work as expected, but i cant just replace the code base.

Comment: Any reason why you are applying the `setPageSize` and `setCurPage` methods whereas those methods are already being applied in the `_applyCollectionModifiers` method ?

Comment: @DigitalPianism not really, i removed the setPageSize and setCurPage now but im still getting one results, the thing is when logging array_values($products) im getting all the products printed, so the problem is most likely to be on how Magento formats the array_values($products) and the entire JSON

Comment: What if you try to use `Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode(array_values($products))` ? Are you able to retrieve a JSON that contains every product ids ?

Comment: @DigitalPianism actually all items are now returned, but they are returned as a single escaped string, not as JSON. So I suspected maybe the an item in $products array is breaking the magento formatter. I'm sharing the json results of the first try here [link](https://gist.github.com/yehiasalam/050462b9461d2311d897)

Comment: @DigitalPianism I added the Mage:helper return [as well](https://gist.github.com/yehiasalam/050462b9461d2311d897)

Comment: Yep works fine with the JSON encoding, I can see the two products. Does that achieve what you wanted ? You only need to decode the JSON now.

Comment: @DigitalPianism not really :( , it's kind of unnatural to decode the array on the magento side, and then decode it again on the client side

Comment: Could you post the result of `array_values($products)` before the return ?

Comment: @DigitalPianism please check my updated question, we're getting closer

Comment: Let's continue this in chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36734/discussion-between-yehia-a-salam-and-digital-pianism

Comment: Why don't you simply return the array `json_encode`d? According to the answer you linked in your question, `string` is a valid return type.

Comment: @simonthesorcerer but i don't think this is the right approach, i should be able to return it as JSON, my second try with the Varien_Data_Collection was resulting the right output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so after a couple of hours of debugging i came up with the right approach. Magento can not work with nested arrays in the return _retrieveCollection function, this is how the collectionOut function is written. So the best way to deal with this is to return the resulting array of the collection and set the total count in the header, something like this:

```
      $products = $collection->load()->toArray();

      $this->getResponse()
            ->setHeader('X-total-count', $collection->getSize() , true);

      return array_values($products); // or just $products
```

Using Varien_Data_Collection is not the right approach even if we were getting the right results, it causes an error as shown in the system.log

```
2016-03-09T23:28:51+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Api2_Model_Acl_Filter::out() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\stage\appfactory-magento\app\code\core\Mage\Api2\Model\Resource.php on line 240 and defined  in C:\stage\appfactory-magento\app\code\core\Mage\Api2\Model\Acl\Filter.php on line 194
```

It was showing the right results because the error was recoverable and the collection has a built-in toJSON function that returns the totalRecords in the fields, it was called by Zend_json:encode when rendering the response (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8388637/226256)